# cant run xampp apache with LabView

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver, xampp, ports, labview

I have xampp installed, and i am using apache with ports 8080 and 4433.
When I installed National Instruments LabView, I couldn't start xampp apache anymore. after reading a bit. LabView includes apache.

Any recommendation on how to run both programs together? or even any tips on how to debug this issue?

**EDIT :**

error message:

```
16:50:25  [Apache]     Status change detected: running
16:50:26  [Apache]     Status change detected: stopped
16:50:26  [Apache]     Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
16:50:26  [Apache]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
16:50:26  [Apache]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
16:50:26  [Apache]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
16:50:26  [Apache]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
16:50:26  [Apache]     If you need more help, copy and post this
16:50:26  [Apache]     entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: You don't specify the error but it sounds as if you simply may need to configure one or the other to run on a different port (or ports).

Comment: my problem is that the error itself is too vague, i'll post it anyway

Comment: @Anaksunaman I actually tried 8080,8888 and 4433 and 4430 on xampp. if it was a port conflict, wont this solve the issue? Besides I ran netstat to check that, no conflict was shown

Comment: To be clear, assuming 8888 and 4430 were specified at the same time in the xampp configuration, then yes that should likely solve any port conflicts (assuming LabView or another process isn't taking those ports as well).

Comment: besides, anybody think this should be on stackoverflow?

Comment: @Anaksunaman Well i have to tell you this, i actually had it work using 8888 right now, but what i did is I installed the apache service for xampp. I don't really know why this worked scientifically. but, that was that

Comment: That does seems an odd solution. But definitely good to know for the future. I am glad you got it solved. =)